# Using Anaconda python with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, anaconda

I'm trying to set up my Apache server to use Anaconda python instead of the system python when using mod_wsgi.

Here is my Apache config file:

```
 LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
 WSGIPythonHome /opt/anaconda/bin
 WSGIPythonPath /opt/anaconda/bin:/opt/anaconda/pkgs
```

As soon as I start the server, my error log is flooded with

```
ImportError: No module named site
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

mod_wsgi is version 4.4.12 and compiled with the same version of python as my anaconda installation (2.7.10).

What am I doing wrong? How do I set up my Apache config file to run python from the non-default location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your Python path is set incorrectly. Go into your Anaconda python and type in:

```
import site
site
```

The directory of your site module should be displayed. It should be something like: `python_path/lib/site.pyc`

Change your Apache configuration to:

```
WSGIPythonPath python_path:python_path/lib/site-packages
```

where `python_path` was the thing you found above when importing `site`.

Comment: Where is that configuration file? Please, complete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party on this but I was having the same problem. To clarify @Ringil's solution, I included something like this in my VirtualHost configuration using the system-installed mod_wsgi:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/path/to/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Note that, as @Ringil points out, the `site-packages` directory needs to be on the `PYTHONPATH`.